# Error: core dumped in a acquisition of a string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to acquire a string in C and verify its length. If this is higher than 6, the code must signal an error and the user must repeat the operation.
The code is this:

```
char string[6];
int result = 0, 
    string_length = 0;

do{
  printf("Insert string: \n");
  result = scanf("%s", string);
  string_length = strlen(string);
  if((result != 1) || (string_length >= 7)){
     printf("Input not allowed try again\n");
     printf("Remember the string must be shorter than 6 character.\n");
  }
  while(getchar() != '\n');
}while((result != 1) || (string_length >= 7));
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You cannot use `"%s"` in scanf to do this.  When using `"%s"`, scanf will consume data until whitespace,  and if there are more than 5 characters it will overflow the buffer.  Among other things, you could use `"%5s"`.

Comment: Don't mix `getchar` and `scanf` unless you know what you are doing.  And read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @WilliamPursell I did what u said and it seems to work. I cannot send an error message to the user in this way but at least it do not crash. The getchar function is used to clean the buffer from any dirt so it must be there, but thanks also for this advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

An array defined as `char string[6];` cannot hold a *string* more than of length 5. What you need to do is to define a buffer longer enough, and then check the string length upon successful user input.

That said, [`scanf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) is prone to buffer overflow and other serious issues, avoid it for taking user inputs. Use [`fgets()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) to read the user input to the buffer, process it, and then check the length of input using [`strlen()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html).